# Fluent nHibernate generates wrong query

Tags: c#, sql-server, pagination, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use pagination for a query. It works when i request the first page but if i request any page after that i'm getting an error.

```
public ProgramMemberResultDTO GetSentFromList(SegmentFilterDTO filter)
{
        var sql = @"SELECT a.Email as Email, a.Phone as Cellphone, mp.mpFirstname as Firstname, mp.mpLastname as Lastname, ISNULL(b.ID, 0) as IsSent FROM
                        ListMember a LEFT JOIN
                        (SELECT this_.ID, this_.Email as Email, this_.Phone as Cellphone
                            FROM ListMember this_ 
                            left join SMSOutgoing sms on sms.PhoneNumber = this_.Phone 
                            left join CampaignSMS cs on cs.SMSID = sms.ID
                            WHERE this_.ListID = :listId AND cs.CampaignListID = :campaignListId) b on a.ID = b.ID
                            INNER JOIN MemberPrograms mp on a.ProgramProfileID = mp.ID
                            WHERE a.ListID = :listId";

        var criteria = _session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);

        criteria.SetParameter("campaignListId", filter.CampaignListId);
        criteria.SetParameter("listId", filter.SelectedList);

        var records = criteria.SetFirstResult(filter.PageNr)
            .SetMaxResults(filter.ResultsPerPage)
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(ProgramMemberDTO))).List<ProgramMemberDTO>();

        var result = new ProgramMemberResultDTO()
        {
            Count = GetNrOfSentFromList(filter.CampaignListId, filter.SelectedList),
            PageNr = filter.PageNr,
            Rows = records
        };

        return result;
}
```

It seems nHibernate is generating an invalid query that the database can't run. This is the query it generates:

> SELECT TOP (@p0) FROM (, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row SELECT a.Email as Email, a.Phone as Cellphone, mp.mpFirstname as Firstname, mp.mpLastname as Lastname, ISNULL(b.ID, 0) as IsSent FROM ListMember a LEFT JOIN (SELECT this_.ID, this_.Email as Email, this_.Phone as Cellphone FROM ListMember this_ left join SMSOutgoing sms on sms.PhoneNumber = this_.Phone left join CampaignSMS cs on cs.SMSID = sms.ID WHERE this_.ListID = @p1 AND cs.CampaignListID = @p2) b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN MemberPrograms mp on a.ProgramProfileID = mp.ID WHERE a.ListID = @p1) as query WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > @p4 ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row <

**EDIT**

This is the error message:

> "could not execute query
>   ↵[ SELECT TOP (@p0)  FROM (, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row SELECT a.Email as Email, a.Phone as Cellphone, mp.mpFirstname as Firstname, mp.mpLastname as Lastname, ISNULL(b.ID, 0) as IsSent FROM
>   ↵                            ListMember a LEFT JOIN
>   ↵                            (SELECT this_.ID, this_.Email as Email, this_.Phone as Cellphone
>   ↵                                FROM ListMember this_ 
>   ↵                                left join SMSOutgoing sms on sms.PhoneNumber = this_.Phone 
>   ↵                                left join CampaignSMS cs on cs.SMSID = sms.ID
>   ↵                                WHERE this_.ListID = @p1 AND cs.CampaignListID = @p2) b on a.ID = b.ID
>   ↵                                INNER JOIN MemberPrograms mp on a.ProgramProfileID = mp.ID
>   ↵                                WHERE a.ListID = @p1) as query WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > @p4 ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row ]
>   ↵  Name:campaignListId - Value:172  Name:listId - Value:110
>   ↵[SQL: SELECT TOP (@p0)  FROM (, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row SELECT a.Email as Email, a.Phone as Cellphone, mp.mpFirstname as Firstname, mp.mpLastname as Lastname, ISNULL(b.ID, 0) as IsSent FROM
>   ↵                            ListMember a LEFT JOIN
>   ↵                            (SELECT this_.ID, this_.Email as Email, this_.Phone as Cellphone
>   ↵                                FROM ListMember this_ 
>   ↵                                left join SMSOutgoing sms on sms.PhoneNumber = this_.Phone 
>   ↵                                left join CampaignSMS cs on cs.SMSID = sms.ID
>   ↵                                WHERE this_.ListID = @p1 AND cs.CampaignListID = @p2) b on a.ID = b.ID
>   ↵                                INNER JOIN MemberPrograms mp on a.ProgramProfileID = mp.ID
>   ↵                                WHERE a.ListID = @p1) as query WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > @p4 ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row]"

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There must be a more explicit error message, is there no inner exception? NHibernate should tell you why it can't execute the query.

Comment: @Rabban this is the inner exception: 
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
↵Incorrect syntax near ')'."

My issue is why is hHibernate creating a wrong query